# Property does not exist on interface

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm confused about how interfaces work in TypeScript.

Here's a chunk of code:

```
interface test1 {
}

class test2 implements test1
{
    public foo;
}

let test: test1 = new test2();

test.foo = 'test';
```

It will not compile and give the error "Property foo does not exist on type test1. So does that mean that when you implement an interface in TypeScript, you can only use the properties and methods declared in the interface?

I'm confused because i'm used to PHP and this will not cause any error in PHP.

Comment: As zmag said, that's the general idea in OOP. (You can read about covariance and contravariance, it's interesting ;) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So does that mean that when you implement an interface in TypeScript, you can only use the properties and methods declared in the interface?

No. That means  when you **reference a variable with specific interface** in TypeScript, you can only use the properties and methods declared in the interface of the variable.

And that is general concept in OOP.

Comment: Ok, i get it and thinking more about it it makes sense, but i was confused because it will not cause an error in PHP, so i wanted to know if it was PHP's behavior that was abnormal or TypeScript's, i have my answer now.

Answer (score 1):

```
let test: test1 = new test2();

test.foo = 'test';
```

You are assigning `test1` as a type of `test` variable, `test1` interface doesn't have `foo` property in it. so that's why you are getting this error. If you change the type to `let test: test2: new test2();`. it won't throw any error:

```
let test: test2 = new test2();

test.foo = 'test';
```

Comment: That would compile indeed, but i want to use an interface so that i can have multiple classes pass the same type check as parameter of a function.

Here is my concrete implementation:
let block: BlockInterface = new QuestionBlock();

function someFunction(block: BlockInterface) { ....}

Answer (score 0):

Think about 2 things here

1. If you want to initialise a variable, there is not need to provide the type.

> ```
> interface test1 { }
> class test2 implements test1{
>     public foo;
> }
> let test = new test2();
> test.foo = 'test';
> ```

2. If you still want to set a type before initialising the value, you have Options.

Option 1

> ```
> interface test1 { }
> class test2 implements test1{
>     public foo;
> }
> let test: test2 = new test2();
> test.foo = 'test';
> ```

Option 2

> ```
> interface test1 { }
> class test2 implements test1{
>     public foo;
> }
> let test: test1 | any = new test2();
> test.foo = 'test';
> ```